# models not getting imported in init.py django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am new to django and was playing around with some code.

I have 5 different models in the models folder, however I am only able to import only 2 into the *init*.py file in models folder.

The only noticeable different between the two files is that the first two do import of `"from django.db import models"` and the rest have `"from my_app.models import *"`

The error I get is, "no module named model3"

All the models (both working and non-working ones) are imported as - `"from my_app.models.model<i> import *"` where i is a number between 1 to 5.

Also, I do not see the error on terminal when I run the server from command line, but on the graphical output. However, if I mess the path up in the import line, say change it to - `"my_project.my_app.models.model<i> import *"`, then an error if no module exists occur on the command line.

I am using virtualenvs, and the django server is linked to apache via wsgi. Python2.7 and Django 1.5

Can anyone help with the problem?

Directory structure:

My_Project

-- My_app

---- Models

------init.py

------model1.py

------model3.py

Comment: perhaps you could post your directory structure, and your exact code?

Comment: Are your apps listed in INSTALLED_APPS in your settings.py file?  You shouldn't manually import any of the models in __init__.py or elsewhere.

Comment: I added the directory structure. I can't share the code. I know its hard otherwise, I am just trying all possibilities here. 
And yes, the only app I have is listed. The different models are inside a single app only.

Comment: Does the my_app directory have an `__init__.py` file too?

Comment: Yes it does. It is simply setting the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to my_app.settings

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the 'app_label' in your model's Meta options. For example,

```
class MyModelName(models.Model):
    <fields>

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'My_app'
```